# Explode string except where surrounded by parentheses?

Tags: php

I'm trying to explode a string by vertical bars. That's the easy part. However, I DON'T want the split to affect substrings that are surrounded by parentheses. That means I need a string such as:

```
Hello (sir|maam).|Hi there!
```

to explode into:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello (sir|maam).
    [1] => Hi there!
)
```

By using the normal explode function, I don't believe there is a way to tell it to ignore that bar surrounded by the parentheses. However, I have some ideas.

I know that it would be possible to do this by exploding the string normally, and then looping through the array and merging everything between strings that contain `(` to the closing string that contains `)`. However, I have a feeling that there should be a more elegant way of achieving this.

Am I right? Is there  a less code-intensive means of spliting a string into an array given these restrictions?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Why you just change the separator to a unique character(s)? like # or even a combination of characters !@#

Comment: @Petra that's the easy part, the regex is the hard part ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can guarantee the parentheses will be balanced and never nested (that is, if there will never be a `'Oops(!'` or a `'(nested stuff (like this)|oops)'`), and there will never be a `||` outside of parentheses that you care to match as an empty string, then this ought to help:

```
preg_match_all('/(?:[^(|]|\([^)]*\))+/', $your_string, $matches);
$parts = $matches[0];
```

It'll match [either (a character that's not a `|` or `(`), or a `(` and `)` enclosing anything that's not a `)` (which includes `|`)], as many times as possible (but at least once).  Short version: it'll make `|` between parentheses part of the match, rather than a separator.

Another possibility, that is slightly less cryptic:

```
$parts = preg_split('/\|(?![^(]*\))/', $your_string);
```

Uses a lookahead assertion to disqualify any `|` that's followed by a `)` if there's not a `(` in between.  Still a bit unforgiving about parens, but it will match empty strings between two `|`s.

Comment: A running example of this can be found on https://onlinephp.io/c/ec7bb

Answer (score 1):

Until someone writes a regex based solution, which I doubt is possible with a single pass, this should work. It is a straightforward translations of requirements to the code.

```
<?php
function my_explode($str)
{
    $ret = array(); $in_parenths = 0; $pos = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++)
    {
        $c = $str[$i];

        if($c == '|' && !$in_parenths) {
            $ret[] = substr($str, $pos, $i-$pos);
            $pos = $i+1;
        }
        elseif($c == '(') $in_parenths++;
        elseif($c == ')') $in_parenths--;
    }
    if($pos > 0) $ret[] = substr($str, $pos);

    return $ret;
}

$str = "My|Hello (sir|maam).|Hi there!";
var_dump(my_explode($str));
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel that using the regex verbs: SKIP and FAIL is the easiest to read/maintain.

Match parenthetical substrings then disqualify them.  If not in a disqualified segment, split the string on any encountered pipes.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JA5lA))

```
var_export(
    preg_split(
        '#\([^)]*\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\|#',
        'Hello (sir|maam).|Hi there!'
    )
);
```