# Exploding string by comma outside parentheses

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that I want to explode by commas but only if the comma is not nested inside some parentheses. This is a fairly common use case, and I have been reading through answered posts in this forum, but not really found what I am looking for.

So, in detail: the point is, i have a string (= SQL SELECT ... FROM statement), and I want to extract the elements from the list separated by comma encoded in this string (= the name of the columns that one wants to select from. However, these elements can contain brackets, and effectively be function calls. For example, in SQL one could do

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(min(shippings.shippingdate), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as shippingdate, nameoftheguy FROM shippings WHERE ...
```

Obviously, I would like to have an array now containing as first element

```
TO_CHAR(min(shippings.shippingdate), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as shippingdate
```

and as second element

```
nameoftheguy
```

The approaches I have followed so far are
[PHP and RegEx: Split a string by commas that are not inside brackets (and also nested brackets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084764/php-and-regex-split-a-string-by-commas-that-are-not-inside-brackets-and-also-n),
[PHP: Split a string by comma(,) but ignoring anything inside square brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50820944/php-split-a-string-by-comma-but-ignoring-anything-inside-square-brackets),
[Explode string except where surrounded by parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918890/explode-string-except-where-surrounded-by-parentheses), and
[PHP: split string on comma, but NOT when between braces or quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233953/php-split-string-on-comma-but-not-when-between-braces-or-quotes)
(focussing on the regex expressions therein, since I would like to do it with a single regex line), but in my little test area, those do not give the proper result. In fact, all of them split nothing or too much:

```
$Input: SELECT first, second, to_char(my,big,house) as bigly, export(mastermind and others) as aloah FROM
$Output: Array ( [0] => first [1] => second [2] => to_char [3] => (my,big,house) [4] => as [5] => bigly [6] => export [7] => (mastermind and others) [8] => as [9] => aloah )
```

The code of my test area is

```
<?php
function test($sql){
    $foo = preg_match("/SELECT(.*?)FROM/", $sql, $match);
    $bar = preg_match_all("/(?:[^(|]|\([^)]*\))+/", $match[1], $list);
    //$bar = preg_match_all("/\((?:[^()]|(?R))+\)|'[^']*'|[^(),\s]+/", $match[1], $list);
    //$bar = preg_match_all("/[,]+(?![^\[]*\])/", $match[1], $list);
    //$bar = preg_match_all("/(?:[^(|]|\([^)]*\))+/", $match[1], $list);
    //$bar = preg_match_all("/[^(,\s]+|\([^)]+\)/", $match[1], $list);
    //$bar = preg_match_all("/([(].*?[)])|(\w)+/", $match[1], $list);
    print "<br/>";
    return $list[0];
}

print_r(test("SELECT first, second, to_char(my,big,house) as bigly, export(mastermind and others) as aloah FROM"));
?>
```

As you can imagine, I am not an regex expert, but I would like to do this splitting in a single line, if it is possible.

Comment: You really should be looking at a proper parser. What will you do if you get a query with a subquery in the select list e.g. `SELECT x, (SELECT y FROM z) AS p, z FROM ...`? Your `$foo = preg_match("/SELECT(.*?)FROM/", $sql, $match);` code will not work properly in that case...

Comment: Assuming all parenthesis are balanced, you could split using something like [`,\s*(?![^(]*\))`](https://regex101.com/r/ye9hpr/1).

Comment: Fair enough. In the first line I probably shouldn't do the regex in the way I do now because of what you just explained. But the second line (the one in question) should in this case (provided there is an answer in the way I imagine it) still return the proper list, i.e. ["x", "(SELECT y FROM z) AS p", "z"].

Comment: @PJProudhon with this I get an error "Warning: preg_match_all(): No ending delimiter ',' found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the conversation here, I did write a parser to solve this problem. It is quite ugly, but it does the job (at least within some limitations). For completeness (if anybody else might run into the same question), I post it here:

```
function full($sqlu){
    $sqlu = strtoupper($sqlu);
    if(strpos($sqlu, "SELECT ")===false || strpos($sqlu, " FROM ")===false) return NULL;
    $def      = substr($sqlu, strpos($sqlu, "SELECT ")+7, strrpos($sqlu, " FROM ")-7);
    $raw      = explode(",", $def);
    $elements = array();
    $rem      = array();
    foreach($raw as $elm){
        array_push($rem, $elm);
        $txt = implode(",", $rem);
        if(substr_count($txt, "(") - substr_count($txt, ")") == 0){
            array_push($elements, $txt);
            $rem = array();
        }
    }
    return $elements;
}
```

When feeding it with the following string

```
SELECT first, second, to_char(my,(big, and, fancy),house) as bigly, (SELECT myVar,foo from z) as super, export(mastermind and others) as aloah FROM table
```

it returns

```
Array ( [0] => first [1] => second [2] => to_char(my,(big, and, fancy),house) as bigly [3] => (SELECT myVar,foo from z) as super [4] => export(mastermind and others) as aloah )
```